# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat8, jpa-2.1

I am trying to upgrade from Tomcat 7.0.63 to 8.5 and running into this NoSuchMethodError exception.  I have hibernate 4.3.8, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, and spring mvc 4.1.4.  the exception trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.xps.XPSConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:478)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
... 34 more
```

Comment: Truly appreciate it, if you could spent a few moment to help out!

Comment: you use maven to get those dependencies?

Comment: no. Tomcat8.5 was download as binary.  everything works with tomcat 7.0.63 before upgrading to tomcat 8.5

Comment: It could be that you have different versions of JPA on classpath - the old one, which is missing `javax.persistence.Table.indexes()` method and is being picked up first, and the new one.

Comment: I was suspecting that.  tomcat 8.5 may have switched the order of class loading such the old definition was loaded first.  tried use vm option verbose:class, did not even see the annotation Table was loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue while migration.Seems your  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar is doing the damage.If you have dual JPA versions it could also lead to issues.Try a Maven build.For the time being remove the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and add the following jars:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.1.8.Final/

Add all these jars to Web-INF/lib It will resolve your issues

Comment: Thanks, Akshay!  tried hibernate 4.1.8.  not working.  same issue.  trying later versions see if that would help.

Comment: I got it resolved.  and many thanks to everybody who were trying to help!  The cause is as many people had suspected.  that is an old jar file that has the old definition hides the correct one.  Tomcat 8.5 has an interesting character.  the order of loading the libraries is different between directories under root and directories under home.  therefore, it works in one directory but not working in another.   That misled me to look at different direction and caused the delay of finding the real cause.

Comment: Kiddos!!I suggest you to go for a clean maven build henceforth as it is a good practice!